# Metodo se ejecuta muchas veces: [style.background-color]="miMetodo(data)"

Tags: angular, typescript, css3, frontend, javascript-metodo

Tengo mi componente HTML un método el cual dependiendo del valor del atributo hará que tenga un background-color, para ello estoy usando la directiva de Angular de esta manera:

```
<div class="flex gap-2 mb-1">
<div class="border-1" style="width: 20px; height:20px" [style.background-color]="customColor(objetivos.objetivosAvance[0].objetivo)">
</div>
<div class="font-bold">
  {{ objetivos.objetivosAvance[0].objetivo.codigoInterno }} (Avance)
</div>
```

Y en mi TS tengo lo siguiente:

```
 customColor(objetivo: ObjetivoModelI) {
  let codInterno = objetivo?.codigoInterno.substring(0,4);
  const color = this.customColors.filter((codigoInterno)=> codigoInterno.name == codInterno);
  console.log(color);
  return color[0]?.value;
 }
```

Todo funciona, pero el problema que tengo es que el método se ejecuta muchas veces, me di cuenta de eso al ver el console.log:

[image: En consola veo las multiples veches que se está ejecutando]

Por lo que he investigado, se debe a que la detección de cambios de angular o algo por el estilo; entonces lo que deseo saber es como puedo hacer para evitar esto, ya que el navegador se pone lento por ratos por las multiples llamadas al metodo.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir una imagen con el número de tus líneas de código? un favor

Comment: Crea una directiva https://angular.io/api/core/Directive